# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Unplug and replug usb wireless keyboard and mouse combo doesn't work

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

I have a Jelly Comb wireless keyboard and mouse combo that uses a single USB receiver.

I have no problems using this keyboard and mouse when I boot up into Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. The problem is, if I unplug the USB receiver dongle and re-plug it in, it does not work.

It seems I can plug in a regular wired keyboard and mouse no problem but doing this with a wireless keyboard and mouse receiver does not work.

I couldn't find any answers to my specific problem. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl -f` as you plug the dongle in, to see what the system thinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that my USB hub/switch was plugged into another computer using a 6ft long cord, this resulted in signal loss. I moved some stuff around to use a shorter cord and it fixed it.